# What could cause the last two lines of a function to not execute?

Tags: javascript, html, function

The last to lines of this js code don't execute unless I put them in another function and execute them with an html input.

```
function baseSize() {
    var available = window.screen.availHeight;

    var windowHeight = window.screen.height;
    var makeHeight = 849 - windowHeight;
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + makeHeight + "px";

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.style.height = available + "px";

    var right = document.getElementById("right");
    right.style.height = available - 230 + "px";

    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    left.style.height = available - 230 + "px";

    var storyright = document.getElementById("storyright");
    storyright.style.height = available - 40 + "px";
}
```

Why is this, and how do I fix it/get around it? (and I know it's probably cluttered, so don't suggest ways to tighten it. I'll get to that later.)

Here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stories.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
    <div id = "container">
    <body onLoad = "baseSize(); storySize();">
    <div id = "head">
        <table class="links">
        <tr>
        <td class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
        <td class="link"><a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a></td>
        <td class="link"><a href="essays.html">Essays</a></td>
        <td class="link"><a href="stories.html">Stories</a></td>
        <td class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id = "icon"><p>Craig InTheDell</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
    <div id="top">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="button"><input type="image" src="mostrecentbutton.jpg" onClick="showContent1()"/></td>
        <td class="button"></td>
        <td class="button"></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div id="storyright">
        <div id="content1">
        <input type = "button" Value = "click me!" onClick = "storySize()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If `var left` doesn't have a `style` or `style.height` property, it could kill the javascript right there.  Look at your console - any errors showing up?

Comment: Good catch... that's a definite possibility as well.

Comment: What do you mean undefined? Doesn't the second to last line define it?

Comment: @Matthew: If an HTML element with the "storyright" ID is not present on the page at the time the JavaScript executes, then `document.getElementById` will return `undefined` which will then be assigned to your `storyright` variable.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that there were no "left" or "right" divs, so I added those in and set display to none for each, and that fixed it. I'm trying to keep all the js for my sight in one file, so there's some overlap.

Comment: @NicholausChipping looks like you were correct, his comment that "everything works but the last two lines" made me believe the style rules were applied to the elements above the storyright element.